# How to make dynamic props for element UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element

I am working on a Element-UI [datepicker](http://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/en-US/component/date-picker#datepicker) component which I wrapped into my own needs.
I want to add one or more props to a default value.

```
pickerOptions: {
  type: Object,
  default: () => ({
    addedProp: '',
    defaultProp: 'firstDayOfWeek: 1',    
  }),
},
```

How can I make `addedProp` be dynamic. How can I setup this prop inside a component. `defaultProp` should always be active as default.
`addedProp` should be like toggleable, only if need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can change your `pickerOptions` to be a computed data, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lczj0ndp/1/

```
    data() {
      return { dynamicValue: '' };
    }
    computed: {
      pickerOptions1() {
        return { 
          someOption: this.dynamicValue,
          ...
        }
      }
```

and then you can make one or more of your options dynamic.

More about computed data you can read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with:

```
        computed: {
          combinedPickerOptions() {
              return {
                  firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                  ...this.pickerOptions,
              };
          },
       },
```

Solution is the spread operator. Now i can set "firstDayOfWeek" as default and set more options if need.